# Spring Boot with Hibernate end points are returning 404

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot I am following this tutorial 
https://github.com/netgloo/spring-boot-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-mysql-springdatajpa-hibernate

All I have done is that downloaded this jar and built it and ran it on localhost:8080

My Application.java which is the main file is as follows:

```
package netgloo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

}
```

My Main Controller is as follows:

```
package netgloo.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class MainController {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  @ResponseBody
  public String index() {
    return "Proudly handcrafted by " + 
        "<a href='http://netgloo.com/en'>netgloo</a> :)";
  }

}
```

My Users Controller is as follows:

```
package netgloo.controllers;

import netgloo.models.User;
import netgloo.models.UserDao;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/user")
public class UserController {

  @Autowired
  private UserDao _userDao;

  @RequestMapping(value="/delete")
  @ResponseBody
  public String delete(long id) {
    try {
      User user = new User(id);
      _userDao.delete(user);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
      return ex.getMessage();
    }
    return "User succesfully deleted!";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/get-by-email")
  @ResponseBody
  public String getByEmail(String email) {
    String userId;
    try {
      User user = _userDao.getByEmail(email);
      userId = String.valueOf(user.getId());
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
      return "User not found";
    }
    return "The user id is: " + userId;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/save")
  @ResponseBody
  public String create(String email, String name) {
    try {
      User user = new User(email, name);
      _userDao.save(user);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
      return ex.getMessage();
    }
    return "User succesfully saved!";
  }

} // class UserController
```

When I type in localhost:8080 I see the message defined in the main controller.

When I type any of the other end points in the UserController e.g. **localhost:8080/user** or **localhost:8080/get-by-email?email=a@gmail.com** it throws a 404.

Please advise what I am missing in this code.

Comment: Please show us the url you're trying to use exactly and the relevant code that verifies the mappings are as you say.

Comment: I have added what you asked @ChiefTwoPencils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying with wrong urls.

Try with these:

```
localhost:8080/user/save?email=a@gmail.com&name=a
localhost:8080/user/get-by-email?email=a@gmail.com
```

Since you are using a `@RequestMapping("/user")` annotation on the class `UserController`, the path `"/user"` is prefixed on all the request mappings in such class. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping) for more info.